# DJANGO REST API - How do I restrict user access to API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

So I’ve been putting together a REST API using William Vincent’s REST API’s with Django book.
I have everything up and going according to the book but I’m a bit of a noob so I need some clarification from the pros.

How can I restrict a user with a token to see certain information within my API?

Created user with Token:
[image]

i added `authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]` to `class UserList` thinking if a user is logged in with a token that logged in user would be able to access that information of my api but I get the below:

[image]

When I remove `authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]`, I get the below.

[image]

All users are able to see my API and I don’t want that, I only want users with a Token to view my api.

Any help is gladly appreciated!

Thanks!
Code below

**# api/views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from .serializers import UserSerializer

# Display List View - User
class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
```

**# api/serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields =('id', 'username', 'email',)
```

**#api/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import  (UserList)

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', UserList.as_view()),    
]
```

**#master_application/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('api/rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),    
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
       'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
       'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication', 
    ]
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to hide and why? It really doesn’t make much of a difference!

Comment: @deceze The information I have in ``User List``. Isn't it best practices for users with a token to only see info within an API? I do front end dev work so I'm used to making things look pretty. I'm just trying to follow best practices.

Comment: Well, when you do `authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]`, then the API basically gives you nothing. Isn't that what you want? I'm not sure what else you're looking for.

Comment: @deceze ok got it. Is it best practices for users without tokens to able to see API information? Or does it even matter?

Comment: What you're looking at there is just a UI. The actual API by necessity exists anyway and can be interrogated by anyone. That UI just makes that more pretty. Personally I switch off this UI in production, but there's really no reason to one way or another.

Comment: @deceze I see. That makes sense. Sounds like I was overthinking it then. Even though I do front end backend api dev work is fun. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readded `authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]`

Tested using `curl -H "Authorization: Token 144eaaf50a50f4055bc50878ee1b3593aa63d221"  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/`
Now I see data in console as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Will leave `authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]` removed. Thanks Everyone.

Comment: Wut? You do want any anonymous user to be able to get a list of users from your API!?

Comment: So leave it then? even if I have ``permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)``? I would make a user for anyone that needs access.

Comment: @deceze so I fixed the issue and tested in the console. The token works and displays data just fine. When I deploy this application I'll just disable the browsable API in production. Thanks!